# Create link with an id : href ="{{ url_for('users/%s'%user[0]) }}" /pb with endpoint and build url (jinja/python/flask )

Tags: url, jinja2, href, endpoint

I am working on a project with 2 app (builded with python/flask).
The first one app. py is the server
The second client.py is the client side.

Now I am building link to acces users/8 from users
But it does'nt work

here under users.html / client.py @route /eror message from jinja

**users.html:**

```
{%block body%}   

        <div class="users">
                <div class="list-group">
                        {% for user in users %}

                        <a href ="{{ url_for('users/%s'%user[0]) }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                        <h5 class="mb-1">{{user[1]}}</h5>
                                        <small>{{user[0]}}</small>
                                </div>
                                <p class="mb-1">{{user[2]}}</p>
                                <small>Know more...</small>
                        </a>

                        {% endfor %}
                </div>


        </div>

{%endblock%}
```

**client.py:**

```py
  @client.route('/users/<id>')#ok works 
 def user(id=None):
     if 'logged_in' in session:
         r = actualUser.get(id)
         user=json.loads(r.text)
         return render_template('user.html', user=user)
     else:
         return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

**error message:**

```
 File "/home/elodieb/Rendu/Python/Flask/flask_d02/ex_03/Client/templates/users.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {%extends "base.html" %}
    File "/home/elodieb/Rendu/Python/Flask/flask_d02/ex_03/Client/templates/base.html", line 44, in top-level template code
    {%block body%}
    File "/home/elodieb/Rendu/Python/Flask/flask_d02/ex_03/Client/templates/users.html", line 12, in block "body"
    <a href ="{{ url_for('users/%s'%user[0]) }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">    
    werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'users/7'. Did you mean 'users' instead?
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty explicit here. The issue is an invalid use of the [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) function within the `users.html` template. You have written this

```python
url_for('users/%s'%user[0])
```

But `url_for` expects an “endpoint” argument (*i.e.* the *name* of the corresponding route, here it is `'users'`) and variables to be passed as keyword arguments. More information and examples on usage here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building

Therefore, what you should replace that template instruction with is

```python
url_for('users', id=user[0])
```

---

You'll probably end-up having other errors after having fixed this though, because you are passing a single `user=user` variable to your template whereas you want to loop over a `users` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `users.html` is looking for an `users` list (see `{% for user in users %}`) and you are passing a single `user` instance (`render_template('user.html', user=user)`).

Either you can modify the template and not use the `for in` loop or update the call to `render_template` like so `render_template('user.html', users=[user])`